# Restangular: How to get HTTP response header?

Tags: http-headers, restangular

I have a REST server which returns a `Link` HTTP header with a response to a PUT to indicate the URL of the newly-created entity:

```
Link:<entities/6>; rel="created"
```

Is there any possibility to read that link header with Restangular?

The only facility to intercept HTTP requests with Restangular I've met so far is to register a response interceptor in the app config:

```
restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    console.log(response.headers())
    return response.data;
});
```

However, with above demo implementation in place, the only HTTP header which gets logged is `content-type`. Still, I can see in the browser development toolbar that a response comes indeed with many additional HTTP response headers, such as `Server`, `Date`, and the aforementioned `Link`.

Why do I not have access to the full array of HTTP response headers through `addResponseInterceptor()`? **Is there any way to capture the HTTP response header in question using Restangular?**

Note: I don't search for an answer using HAL or any other special response body format. I would rather like to know whether I can use plain HTTP headers with Restangular or not (if not, I will probably resort to HAL or something).

Comment: Hi!Does the anwer help you to solve the issue? keep in ind that the edit suggested by STEVER is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a `ResponseInterceptor` to do this. You just need to set `fullResponse` to `true` to get the whole response (including the http headers) every time you do any request.

```
Restangular.setFullResponse(true);
```

You can set it globally in your app configuration. Something like this:

```
angular.module('YourApp')
     .config(['RestangularProvider',
       function (RestangularProvider) {
         RestangularProvider.setFullResponse(true);
...
```

Then, every time you receive a response, you can access all the response headers.

```
Restangular.all('users').getList().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
    console.log(response.headers);
}
```

Example:

```
response.headers('Link')
```

*NOTE:* Be careful because using fullResponse, the response data is located in response.data, not directly in response.

**EDIT**: As @STEVER points, you also need to [expose the headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) in your server API.
Example:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link
```

You can get more detailed information in [Restangular documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setfullresponse)

Hope it helps.

Comment: also don't forget to set correct https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Thanks @STEVER! You're right, I forgot to mention it. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you troig and STEVER, it does work! However, I also needed to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`. Don't know how this is related. Also, I manage to implement this as a locally "derived" Restangular service, as in https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one, allowing me to use this behavior specifically on certain pages.